# Displaying a system of equations in the variables x and y

Tags: align, systeme

Why isn't `LaTeX` displaying a system of equations properly using the following code?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}


\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\systeme{y - k = \mathrlap{m(x - h)}, (x - h)^{2} + (y - k)^{2} = \mathrlap{r^{2}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `systeme` is made for systems of linear equations.

Answer (score 3):

No need for the `systeme` machinery. A simple `align*` environment and a well-chosen `\phantom` directive suffice to get the job done. Here, I'm assuming that an important part of the "job" is to align the two `y-k` terms across the two rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y - k\phantom{)^2} &= m(x - h)\\
(x - h)^{2} + (y - k)^{2} &= r^{2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solution?!**

Pass the order of variables to the command. But note that the LHS of 1st equation is not right aligned.

```
\begin{equation*}
\systeme[xhyk]{%
                y - k      = m(x - h),%
 (x - h)^{2} + (y - k)^{2} = r^{2}}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: looks like you left a blank line before `equation` in your full example.  if not, womething else fishy is going on to mess up the vertical spacing.

Comment: @barbara beeton  I have an `align` environment not an `equation` environment.  My complaint is not about vertical spacing!  In the display of the first equation, the "y" is artificially shifted rightwards and the "+" shouldn't even be there. In the display of the second equation, the "(x" and "(y" are artificially shifted rightwards.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I guess that I used `\lipsum` instead of `\lipsum*` so it inserted a paragraph.

Comment: @Adelyn -- i was chiding Sigur about the output of the example in his answer.  he has explained what happened, and i agree with his analysis.  i actually don't know `systeme`, and i hadn't tried out the example in your question, so the comment wasn't directed at that.